# Latex beamer error: argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. \end{frame}

Tags: latex, figure, beamer, tikz

I'm trying to put together a presentation using latex beamer. I drew a triangle using the `tikz` package but I can't put the names on the angles. When executing the code, the following error appears: "*Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }. \end{frame}*"

The code is:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt,serif]{beamer} % serif, mathserif

\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{ae}                      

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{-3pt}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}              
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}              
\usepackage{icomma}                 
\usepackage{bm}                    
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}  

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (C) at (-1.5,-1);
                \coordinate (A) at (1.5,-1);
                \coordinate (B) at (1.5,1);
                \coordinate (D) at (1.5,-3);
                \node [below] at (3,-1) {$\Re$};
                \node [above] at (-1.5,2) {$\Im$}; 
        
                %draw cartesian plane
                \draw[stealth-stealth] (-1.5,-4) -- (-1.5,2) coordinate (y axis);
                \draw[-stealth] (C) -- (3,-1) coordinate (x axis);
                
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}] (C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,sloped,above] {$S_{abc}$} (B);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](A) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.7,right] {$Q_{abc}$} (B);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.8,above] {$P_{abc}$} (A);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,sloped,below] {$S_{abc}$} (D);
                \draw[very thick,{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}-](D)-- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.3,right] {$-Q_{abc}$} (A) ;
                
                \pic[thick,"$\theta$", draw=blue,-stealth, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
                {angle=A--C--B};
                \pic[thick,"$\theta$", draw=red, stealth-, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=0.9cm]
                {angle=D--C--A};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you have fragile content in your frame, like certain tikz pictures, use the `fragile` frame option.

Some other comments:

- the `serif` class option is obsolete. A warning in the log file will tell you to use the `serif` font theme instead, but as you already do this, there is really no reason to use this class option
- if your tex distribution isn't terrible outdated, you no longer need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
- there are two `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]`
- you don't need `color` and the `ams`* packages, beamer already loads them for you

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,10pt]{beamer} % serif, mathserif

\usepackage[english,brazil]{babel}         
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        
\usepackage{ae}                      

\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{-3pt}
%\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\scriptsize}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}

%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{amsmath}              
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}              
\usepackage{icomma}                 
\usepackage{bm}                    
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes,babel}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}  

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{CambridgeUS}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Frame Title}
        \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \coordinate (C) at (-1.5,-1);
                \coordinate (A) at (1.5,-1);
                \coordinate (B) at (1.5,1);
                \coordinate (D) at (1.5,-3);
                \node [below] at (3,-1) {$\Re$};
                \node [above] at (-1.5,2) {$\Im$}; 
        
                %draw cartesian plane
                \draw[stealth-stealth] (-1.5,-4) -- (-1.5,2) coordinate (y axis);
                \draw[-stealth] (C) -- (3,-1) coordinate (x axis);
                
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}] (C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,sloped,above] {$S_{abc}$} (B);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](A) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.7,right] {$Q_{abc}$} (B);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.8,above] {$P_{abc}$} (A);
                \draw[very thick,-{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}](C) -- 
                    node[font=\Large,sloped,below] {$S_{abc}$} (D);
                \draw[very thick,{Stealth[length=3mm, width=1.5mm]}-](D)-- 
                    node[font=\Large,pos=0.3,right] {$-Q_{abc}$} (A) ;
                
                \pic[thick,"$\theta$", draw=blue,-stealth, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
                {angle=A--C--B};
                \pic[thick,"$\theta$", draw=red, stealth-, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=0.9cm]
                {angle=D--C--A};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```